# Nuxt "Dist" Error when deploying the project to vercel? how do i fix it?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel

Error: `No Output Directory named "dist" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings. Learn More: https://vercel.link/missing-public-directory Deployment completed STATIC_BUILD_NO_OUT_DIR: No Output Directory named "dist" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.`

I tried `npm run build` it didn't work.

Comment: Have you followed the documentation about how to deploy Nuxt 3 apps on Vercel? https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/vercel

Comment: That’s how I did it. I tried updating nuxt, re-installing node-modules, and running nudt build nothing worked, note that I get the error in the deployment process